# Swift not firing touchesBegan if swipe

Tags: swift, touchesbegan

Hello I have a swift application where I have touches began to call a function every time, but I don't want touchesBegan to be called if the user is swiping instead. How can I avoid this?

Touches began:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
//function call
}
```

Swipe:

```
var Swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
    Swipe.direction = .Up
    //Swipe.cancelsTouchesInView = true        did not make a difference
    view.addGestureRecognizer(Swipe)
```

Also I do not want to do touches Ended as that adds a delay I can not have

Answer (score 0):

Make your UIViewController's view a custom class and handle these touches there - they should be received the way you tried it but only in the UIView class itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate swipes from touches you can do easily with the delaysTouchesBegan method, for example :

```
        let swipeRight:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedRight:"))
        swipeRight.direction = .Right
        swipeRight.cancelsTouchesInView = true
        swipeRight.delaysTouchesBegan = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)


        let swipeLeft:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedLeft:"))
        swipeLeft.direction = .Left
        swipeLeft.cancelsTouchesInView = true
        swipeLeft.delaysTouchesBegan = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)


        let swipeUp:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedUp:"))
        swipeUp.direction = .Up
        swipeUp.cancelsTouchesInView = true
        swipeUp.delaysTouchesBegan = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)


        let swipeDown:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedDown:"))
        swipeDown.direction = .Down
        swipeDown.cancelsTouchesInView = true
        swipeDown.delaysTouchesBegan = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
```

in your viewDidLoad or didMoveToView (if you are in a spritekit scene)

And make the respectively methods :

```
func swipedRight(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
   print("swiped right")
}

func swipedLeft(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
   print("swiped left")
}

func swipedUp(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
   print("swiped up")
}

func swipedDown(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
   print("swiped down")
}
```

Then you can control your touches with the official delegate methods like :

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
...// handle your touches..
}
```